# How can I talk to the Business objects Instance on server(BO Infoview) for a windows app c#

Tags: c#, business-objects

we have BO Infoview runnig on our servrer. I would like to establish connection to it from a local windows app in C#. Do we have any API's for BO infoview??

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any direct API to the Infoview product.  The API does provide full access to recreate the Infoview interface if you so choose.

If you really want Infoview wrapped in a full client, then I would recommend just providing an IE control that is hardwired to your Infoview site.

If you chose to recreate the interface, I recommend wrapping the API in simpler to use objects, since there is a large amount of overhead to getting authenticated and handling opening a document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the openDocument URL commands: http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_java_dg_doc/doc/boesdk_java_dg/Report_Linking.html

Thanks,

Matt